# Having some trouble with try-except in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, try-except

So I wrote this function wich returns a meaning of a word that is in data.json. The problem is that the return works fine when I put some right word the first time, but after one exception it returns None.

```
def sig_palavra(p):
    p = p.lower()
    try:
        return str(data[p])
    except:
        print('Verifique se a palavra foi escrita corretamente')
        p = input(':')
        p = p.lower()
        sig_palavra(p)
```

I have this output:

```
> Digite a palavra pra saber seu significado: olho
> Verifique se a palavra foi escrita corretamente
>:eye
> None
```

But 'eye' is a valid word and it returns its meaning if I write it in the first place

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement in the `except` block.

Comment: Use `return sig_palavra(p)`

Comment: You shouldn't use recursion in Python as a replacement for iteration.

Comment: Why shouldn't? Can you explain it better?

Comment: Because iteration is generally easier to understand, the looping is obvious.